How to create good model instances
I am currently writing my first paper in the field of operations research. I am solving a nurse rostering problem. I am wondering how to set up model instances in a meaningful way. What should I pay attention to? What should you not pay attention to? For example, could results not be biased if I use a special demand profile or something similar? Currently, my profile is randomly distributed across my shifts based on a distribution I have determined.

Some related posts that may be interesting. 1, 2, 3, 4.

You might be able to use the instances from https://nrpcompetition.kuleuven-kulak.be/ and https://mobiz.vives.be/inrc2/

Might be worth comparing your solution with our implementation for the International Nurse Rostering Competition. Follow Rob's link above for the datasets.

If you are working with an organization that would actually put your model into practice, it would make sense to ask them for some real-world examples. Beyond that, you could look for related research and see if any of those papers included enough information to produce comparable profiles.

In addition to @prubin's answer I would also suggest to go on the hunt for difficult instances. By that I mean, instead of creating instances according to a single pattern, try to generate multiple different types of instances, all trying to replicate different scenarios that might come up. That could for instances be instances with high demand in evening/morning shifts, evenly distributed demand, few wards, many wards, many nurses, few nurses and so on.
Then try to figure out which of these instances are hard and more interestingly why these instances are hard to solve using your model/algorithm. It is often more interesting to demonstrate what a hard instance looks like, than just reporting that your algorithm could solve all the instances generated using your chosen generation scheme within a certain time limit.
